# "RadioGroup" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, parsing, radio-group

I am having been following a beginners tutorial and I have encountered this error which i can't seem to understand or solve.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText android:text="" 
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"     
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"  
            android:gravity="center"  
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Style" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvGravity" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Gravity" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"     
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2" 
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioGroup android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/rgStyle"

            <RadioButton  android:id="@+id/rbNorm"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Normal" />
            <RadioButton  android:id="@+id/rbIta"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Italic" />   
            <RadioButton  android:id="@+id/rbBold"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bold" />  
        </RadioGroup>

        <RadioGroup android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/rgGravity"
            <RadioButton  android:id="@+id/rbLeft"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Left" />    
            <RadioButton  android:id="@+id/rbCenter"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Center" />    
            <RadioButton  android:id="@+id/rbRight"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Right" />
        </RadioGroup>       

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView  android:id="@+id/tvChange" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Type In Text And Press Button Below" />

    <Button  android:id="@+id/bGenerate" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Generate" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I keep getting the error-'Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)'on the 34th line and 'Element type "RadioGroup" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"' on the next line.

---

Help me please I'm a newbie

Comment: Please remember to format your code properly by the way, text in angle brackets will not be visible unless indented with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing the `>` from the following places

```
<RadioGroup android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/rgGravity"
```

and

```
<RadioGroup android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/rgStyle"
```

Answer (score -1):

mate you cant use `/>` and `</RadioGroup>` choose one of them..
check the example here [RadioGroup example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/radiogroup/android-radiogroup-example/)

Answer (score -2):

Thanks I found out that the error were due to the way i formatted the code...i corrected it by simply using Ctr+Shift+F

Comment: That's not quite correct, the error was that your XML was not well formed. Your IDE may have corrected this automatically for you when you chose to autoformat, but the formatting itself was not the real issue.